# search for the date cells in dataframe to change format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i have some excel files
[here is a sample of one of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ8kS.png)

I Want to change the format of the dates, but the problem is not all the files have the same format and pattern, and doesn't have names for the columns, therefore i would like to search dynamicaly for the dates and change them, i know how to do when i know the position of the data but in my case i don't know how to do it

```
file = pd.read_excel('b.xlsx')
file = file.astype(str)
file = file.drop(file.index[:8])

file= file.replace({'2020': '20'}, regex=True)  
file = file.iloc[:, 0]

file = pd.to_datetime(file)
file = file.dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```